# Send variable to 3rd party online form

Tags: forms, http, go

In golang, is there a way to pipe a variable to part of a web form?
 For example, sending `"123 Random St."` to the `Street address` part of https://www.dominos.com/en/pages/order/#/locations/search/  and so on?    I found `pizza_party*`, but the `GUI` used is no longer available, I have also found `pizzadash**`, but this uses a credit card where I want to use cash. I even found a list of golang ones, but the links that they use doesn't work anymore.`***`
Therefore, my goal is so: `order a pizza in golang through the dominos website API!`

NOTE: Please suggest a package or function **with example**!

NOTE: I do not want to make a web scraper/data getter.

NOTE: Your answer must work on **at least** one box of my linked website.

NOTE: I want to fill out links similar to the provided link from the linux command line.

`*`https://github.com/coryarcangel/Pizza-Party-0.1.b
`**`https://github.com/bhberson/pizzadash
`***`https://golanglibs.com/top?q=pizza

Comment: This is not clear to me. You mention interacting with buttons but also working from the linux command line. Do you want to run a command and order a pizza or do you want a GUI? If its the former this is a simple matter of making an http request isn't it?

Comment: i want to order a pizza from the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you post any form values onto an online form. Provided you know the POST endpoint of the service.

```
func main():

   resp, err := http.PostForm(targetPostUrlHere,
    url.Values{"Service_Type": {"Delivery"}, 
        "Address_Type_Select": {"House"}, 
        "Street": {"123 E 24th St"}, 
        "Address_Line_2": {"4D"}, 
        "City": {"New York"},
        "Region": {"NY"},
        "Postal_Code": {"10027"}})

}
```

**Note: The field keys and values are guesstimates. You must inspect the actual key names expected in the form.

In your case, https://www.dominos.com/en/pages/order/ is an endpoint for the form page. Once the form is filled and submitted, the information is submitted using POST method akin to the code afore-mentioned to a dedicated CREATE endpoint (C in the [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)), which normally can be found in the `<form>` html tag.

```
<form action="posttargetendpoint" method="POST">...</form>
```

Once the POST operation is successful, usually a web service would redirect you to another page. In your case, it is https://www.dominos.com/en/pages/order/#/section/Food/category/AllEntrees/

However, any good web service wouldn't expose the POST endpoint in the clear since it is the vulnerable point of attack. You're welcome to find out by inspect he Domino's page source and adjust the field values in the Go code accordingly.

Now to make a command line prompt to wrap around the `PostForm` code, I suggest you look into https://github.com/codegangsta/cli which is a very nice package for creating quick command line app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean pipe information originating from your backend to another site on behalf of a user?

The standard way of passing information between domains is via HTTP params, usually via a GET request, but this capability would need to be supported by established protocols the remote site. You can also use an iframe to embed the page of another site onto your page, however, you wouldn't be able to remotely interact, call JS code, or even query the page at all. Cross-domain security safeguards justifiably prohibit such capability, and generally speaking, interacting on behalf of the user via their browser is also restricted for security reasons.

However, if you're looking to emulate user behavior such as with a bot or web scraper from your own host or browser then that's a different story. There are tons of frameworks provide rich capability for interacting with a page. I'd recommend checking out Selenium, which acts as a virtual browser. There are also tons of libraries in Python for processing data from HTML and structured data. You might want to check out Beatiful Soup and Scrapy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Whoa. I am not trying to make a web scraper, I want to fill out the form from the linux command line.